# Antipodal mapping of the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a closed form $d\omega=0$ on $S^{n}$. If $i: S^{n} \to S^{n}$ is the antipodal map, it induces a decomposition $\Omega^{n}(S^{n})=\Omega^{n}_{+}(S^{n})\oplus \Omega^{n}_{-}(S^{n})$, where $\Omega^{n}_{\pm}(S^{n})$ are invariant or anti-invariont from antipodal map, i.e. $i^{*}\omega=\pm\omega $. I don't understand why form is contained either in $\Omega^{n}_{+}(S^{n})$ or $\Omega^{n}_{-}(S^{n})$,  why there is no such forms on the sphere which does not fall within these classes. And if I'm right, the fact that $i^{*}(d\omega)=d\omega$ or $i^{*}(d\omega)=-d\omega$  induces a decomposition between cohomology $H^{n}(S^{n})=H^{n}_{+}(S^{n})\oplus H^{n}_{-}(S^{n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an $n$-form $\omega$ on $S^n$, it is not necessarily the case that $\omega \in \Omega^n_+(S^n)$ or $\omega \in \Omega_-(S^n)$; however, $\omega \in \Omega_+(S^n)\oplus\Omega_-(S^n)$. That is, every $n$-form $\omega$ on $S^n$ can be written uniquely as $\omega = \omega_+ + \omega_-$ where $\omega_{\pm} \in \Omega_{\pm}(S^n)$. This decomposition is given by $\omega_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(\omega \pm i^*\omega)$; note, this works precisely because $i^*$ is an involution on $\Omega^n(S^n)$ (i.e. $i^*\circ i^* = \operatorname{id}_{\Omega^n(S^n)}$).

Comment: and how to show that any form of $S^{n}$ can be written uniquely as $\omega=\omega_{+}+\omega_{-}$?

Comment: The decomposition in my answer shows that any form can be written in such a way. For uniqueness, suppose we also have $\omega = \alpha + \beta$ with $\alpha \in \Omega_+(S^n)$ and $\beta \in \Omega^n_-(S^n)$, then $i^*\omega = \alpha - \beta$. Combining, we get $$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}((\alpha + \beta) + (\alpha - \beta)) = \frac{1}{2}(\omega + i^*\omega) = \omega_+$$ and $$\beta = \frac{1}{2}((\alpha+\beta) - (\alpha-\beta)) = \frac{1}{2}(\omega - i^*\omega) = \omega_-.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! And can you say,i am wright about the decomposition in cohomology?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely what John said in his answer to your last question.